# Random image on Stack Overflow search result on Google Search

Tags: discussion, support

Today I searched Google for steps on how to do something (hoping to find a Stack Overflow post):

> convert string to byte array

It showed me this page: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=convert+string+to+byte+array&*

[image]

As you can see, it has a picture saying something about the FBI.

The image links to the same stack Overflow post and clicking the link: *[Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)* doesn't show the image anywhere.

Where has this image been served up from? Is it Google displaying this image or is it Stack Overflow? Why has this image been selected, it doesn't seem to add anything to the Google post?

Comment: I don't see this image. Maybe one of your extensions is injecting it?

Comment: Or maybe it from the ads? Googling this [image](http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/ac8052b3299c4711a3d284ad1a07d988.jpg) shows other stackoverflow questions in the results

Comment: I can confirm I see the same thing. It does seems to be a base64 jpeg image instead of a link to an existing (or deleted) image on SO. Extensions do not seem to affect this. I wonder if indeed Google is caching and associating a previously served up ad.

Comment: Strangely, [not repro'd here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwML0.png), using Chrome 57, Windows 10, no extension (incognito mode).

Comment: I'm using `Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87` on `Windows 10`. I see the image in both **normal** and **Incognito** mode. After updating, still shows in V57

Comment: Looks like a weird bug on Google's side, which cached that image for all Stack Overflow posts somehow.

Comment: The thing that disturbs me the most is that the image is pretty creepy.

Comment: On another note, this isn't limited to Chrome. Every browser I tried shows this, so it won't be an extension issue.

Comment: Well, the FBI actually got [page on Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/138704/special-agent-federal-bureau-of), likely the ad link to this page. Though it does not explain why Google cached it.

Comment: And they're watching us..watching us..

Comment: The pic doesn't show up for me, i am using firefox i am having ad blocker , I even reloaded the page by disabling ab blocker still i didn't see any picture.

Comment: It's a secret invitation to you by FBI. Kidding aside, I suggest try to reproduce the error/bug.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: Strangely today The image is now gone

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Chrome on OS X Sierra.